# Javascript/jquery does not load with mod_rewrite on

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm still struggling with the workings of `mod_rewrite`. So my test page request works well until I turn on `mod_rewrite`.

This is the .htaccess directive

```
RewriteRule     ^.*$    scripts/index.php
```

And the target PHP file has these:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libraries/colorbox-master/jquery.colorbox-min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js" ></script>
    <title>index.php</title>
</head>
```

And just testing out the index.js file with:

```
console.log('Hello world');
```

I get this browser console error messages with mod_rewrite turned on:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://web3.loc/js/index.js". index.php:7
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                    index.js:2
```

Comment: What does the head section and any relevant scripts look like when you do View/Source in the browser?  That is where you can see what was actually served to the browser so you can see what it is actually doing to your files.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's the same as I presented above.

Comment: I'll be you that `index.js` is not the same as you expect since that's where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you preceed your rule with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

it will not be evaluated if an existing file or directory is requested and the requested ressource will be served instead of your index.php.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html